# Alter JSON response in nestjs

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

i am using node,nestjs and mongoose i write a get call and get the result like

```
[
 {
    "_id": "5d4a9c0b1a6bcf14775c953c",
    "material_name": "ramboo",
    "material_status": 0,
    "is_admin_approved": true,
    "createdAt": "2019-08-07T09:38:19.237Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-08-07T09:38:19.237Z",
    "id": "5d4a9c0b1a6bcf14775c953c"
}
]
```

the service like this (material.service.ts)

```
async findAll(): Promise<IDMaterial[]> {
  return await this.materialModel.find({is_admin_approved: true});
  }
```

how to remove is_admin_approved field from the result like

```
[
 {
    "_id": "5d4a9c0b1a6bcf14775c953c",
    "material_name": "ramboo",
    "material_status": 0,
    "createdAt": "2019-08-07T09:38:19.237Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-08-07T09:38:19.237Z",
    "id": "5d4a9c0b1a6bcf14775c953c"
}
]
```

how to solve this issue any way please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could omit `is_admin_approved` from each object in the array using lodash's [omit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit) function:

```
async findAll(): Promise<Partial<IDMaterial>[]> {
  return this.materialModel
    .find({is_admin_approved: true})
    .then(data => data.map(item => _.omit(item.toObject(), 'is_admin_approved')));
}
```

---

You could also mark `is_admin_approved` as `@Exclude` in your `IDMaterial` dto class and then cast retrieved items to this dto (`plainToClass(IDMaterial, item)`).

```
export class IDMaterial {
   // ...
   @Exclude()
   is_admin_approved: boolean;
  // ...
}

// ...
async findAll(): Promise<Partial<IDMaterial>[]> {
  return this.materialModel
    .find({is_admin_approved: true})
    .then(data => data.map(item => plainToClass(IDMaterial, item)));

}
```

Comment: src/feature/material/material.service.ts(13,7): error TS2322: Type 'IDMaterial[] | { _id: any; material_name: String; }[]' is not assignable to type 'IDMaterial[]'.
[2]   Type '{ _id: any; material_name: String; }[]' is not assignable to type 'IDMaterial[]'.
[2]     Type '{ _id: any; material_name: String; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IDMaterial': material_status, is_admin_approved, increment, model, and 54 more.

Comment: Mark `is_admin_approved` as optional (`is_admin_approved?`) in `IDMaterial` or use `Promise<Partial<IDMaterial>[]>` as return value for `findAll` method.

Comment: I also see a lot of other fields in `IDMaterial` entity, not only `"_id", "m_name", "is_admin_approved"`. So you might omit `is_admin_approved` instead of re-map all other fields. I'll update the answer

Comment: src/feature/material/material.service.ts(16,18): error TS2704: The operand of a delete operator cannot be a read-only property. --- this is new error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197667/discussion-between-ihor-sakaylyuk-and-andrew-ghosh).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code can help you. Store the results, then iterate and delete item from each object you fetched. Then return that changed array of objects.

```
async findAll(): Promise<IDMaterial[]> {
  const result = await this.materialModel.find({is_admin_approved: true});
  result.map(elem => delete elem.is_admin_approved)
  return result;
}
```

Comment: The operand of a delete operator cannot be a read-only property. show this error

Comment: Hm... Works well in codePen with const, anyway, instead of "const" switch to "let" and it should work.